# In Wildfly Server 12 having concern with split function used in JavaScript

Tags: wildfly

In our project currently we are using wildfly 9 server, so are planning to upgrade wildly server 12.

However, while doing testing we found some error regarding split function using in JavaScript.

Ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function testSplitFunction(){
     var data="input$output";
     var variable1 = data.split("\\$")[0];
     var variable2 = data.split("\\$")[1];
}

</script>
```

This above function is working as expected in wildfly server 9 and we are getting the result as bellow
variable1= input;
variable2 = output;

But same function in wildfly server 12 we are getting the following result:

```
variable1= input$output;
variable2 = undefined;
```

Is their any solution to overcome this problem in wildfly server 12? In our project we are using this split more times.

Comment: Where are you running this?  Is this a page sent to a browser?  Or are you running JavaScript within Wildfly with the `ScriptEngine`?

Comment: This code block present in JSP file within script tag, and we are deploying our project in wildfly server 12. When user performing some actions on user interface we are calling this JavaScript function

Comment: You may want to debug the JavaScript and/or look at the generated source. The JavaScript will be run on the client side not the server.